I got this error : "This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used" while trying to get the current location via flutter_osm
The error message I'm encountering indicates that the currentLocation() method is defined to return Future<void>, which means it does not return any value, and thus I cannot assign its result to a variable.
  Widget origin() {
    return Positioned(
      bottom: 20,
      right: 15,
      left: 15,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
// the error is on this line 
 GeoPoint currentLocation = await mapController.currentLocation();

            debugPrint(
                "Current Location: Latitude: ${currentLocation.latitude}, Longitude:   ${currentLocation.longitude}");

            await mapController.addMarker(
              markerPosition: currentLocation,
              markerIcon: MarkerIcon(
                iconWidget: markerIcon,
              ),
            );

            setState(() {
              geoPoint.add(currentLocation);
              widgetStateList.add(destinationState);
            });
          } catch (e) {
            debugPrint("Error getting current location: $e");
          }
        },
        child: const Text(MyStrings.originSelect),
      ),
    );
  }


You can get the current location using the myLocation() function.
The function currentLocation() indeed returns Future<void> and moves the map to the current user location.
